# 2 wire thermostat, control relay

Tags: wiring, thermostat, relay

I currently have a 750mv propane stove in my living room. It is connected to a battery powered Honeywell programmable thermostat with 2 wires.

The thermostat supports AC and fan.

I have in my living room 2 110v ceiling fans.

I would like to wire the thermostat to a relay so when the stove turns on the fans turn on also.

Do I need to add a C-Wire to the thermostat and a relay to trigger the fans? Or can it be done with just a relay and the battery power from the thermostat?

Anyone have any ideas or have done this before?

Comment: Do you still want to be able to use the stove if the power goes out?

Answer (score 1):

You have a millivolt furnace.  You need to use a millivolt thermostat for that, not a programmable 'stat which is intended for 24V furnaces.  Millivolt thermostats need to switch much higher current, so they need to be made for the service.

Typically, millivolt thermostats are used when a furnace has no electrical requirements at all, and can function normally with the AC power grid down. *I have one, and I consider it fairly important to NOT break its 'grid-down' capability.

**There is no *electrical* way**  to connect the fans to the millivolt 'stat.  The thermocouple which is the source of the voltage does not have any spare energy to operate a relay coil, nor even a reed switch.

However, I submit to you that you don't want to do that *anyway*.

If you listen to any forced-air furnace do its thing, you can hear the gas fire for many seconds *before* the forced-air blower kicks on.  That's to let the heat exchanger warm up first so you aren't blowing cold air around the house.  It also runs the fan for awhile *after* the gas shuts off, so as not to waste the heat remaining in the heat exchanger.

Your fans should do exactly the same thing. They should be actuated by a thermostat on the stove that says the stove is warm enough to justify circulating air.  I would wire that with 24V using a relay such as a RiB or Aube or "relay-transformer in a 4x4 junction box lid" or some such, because that would be the easiest to make Code legal.  It's a perfect job for an Aube.

Comment: It's a programmable thermostat compatible with 750mv. It's already hooked up and working fine.

Comment: OP mentions that he has a battery powered themostat, so not depending on  the grid.

Answer (score 0):

you wont be able to share the thermostat contacts between the fan relay and the stove, so you'll need two relays, one installed in an electrical panel or box to control the fans, and a second to control the stove, plus you'll need a transformer to power the relays.

you could possilbly add an always on relay to that connects the thermostat to directly to the furnace during power outages.